# Proxy for Selenium works locally but returns empty pages in Heroku

Tags: selenium-webdriver, heroku, proxy

I have a Selenium script that needs to access a website through a turkish server. Since Heroku doesnt offer turkey as a server location, i wanted to proxy the traffic.

```
    public ChromeOptions options;
    public WebDriver driver;

    public Chrome() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver");
        options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--window-size=2560,1440");
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--proxy-server=ip:port");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

```
 driver.get("https://www.whatsmyip.org/");
 System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ip\"]")).getText());
```

This printed my the turkish ip, that i set in the options.

However, printing the page source shows, that after deployment to heroku, I only get empty pages back.

Online I couldnt find any solutions to this.